# Why does this output 5?

Tags: java

My understanding is x++ == 0 runs first. But x is still -1 at the point of calculating (y = y++ / x) == 0? Otherwise it will be dividing by zero. I thought the output will be -5 but eclipse says 5. I'm going crazy.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        
    int x = -1;
    int y = 5;
    boolean s = (x++ == 0) && ((y = y++ / x) == 0);
    System.out.println(x + y);
}
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`((y = y++ / x) == 0)` is never evaluated since `&&` is a short circuited logical AND operator, and `(x++ == 0)` is `false`, so `s` is evaluated to `false` without evaluating the second operand.

Hence, the output is

```
x + y

0 + 5 == 5
```

Note that if you change the `&&` operator to `&`, which is **not** short circuited, the second operand will be evaluated, which will lead to division by `0` and `ArithmeticException`. `x` is incremented when the first operand is evaluated, so once the second operand is evaluated, `x` is already `0`.